# Modifying nouns without relative pronouns or relative proverbs

Tags: modifiers, appositives

Do those sentences below sound natural?

> 1.*She’s got that hair the color of chestnut*.(Modified by the objective)
>
> 2.*I looked in the mirror the size of my two hands*.(Modifies by the objective)
>
> 3.*I saw the view, an older man criticizing a young man*.(Modified by the gerund clause)
>
> 4.*My favorite sport, playing the baseball, has brought me friends*.(Modified by the gerund clause)

And if these don’t really sound natural, can you give me an example using the same technique as in the ().

And also I want to know what kind of nouns collocate well with the way of modifying as in the ().

Answer (score 1):

None of these are very good. The phrase doesn't modify anything.  It appears to be a stand-alone phrase.  These might appear in speech, functioning as a "for example" or "which is" phrase.  These might be called "appositive".

1.She’s got hair (which is) the color of chestnut.  (this apposition works like a relative clause)

2.I looked in the mirror the size of my two hands. (This is not grammatical.  It needs "at the size..."

3.I saw the view, (the view was) an older man criticizing a young man. (This works as an appositive.)

4.My favorite sport, playing baseball, has brought me friends. (again, appositive)

Comment: I can't see any reason for not saying that the NP "the color of chestnut" is modifying "hair". NPs as post-head modifiers of nouns are quite common, cf. "a woman my age". "someone your own age", "a rug this colour" and so on.

Comment: Thank you bill j, are you saying that to the answer given by James k?